# Overwrite the Symfony translator

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.4

I'd like to add the possibility to do in place translations to my website. So when someone has the rights to do translations in a given language they can just open a page and change or add translations.

Therefore I need to get a complete list of all translated messages keys/ids on a given site.

I tried to use a `DataCollectorTranslator` that I fed with `translator.default` but that always shows zero messages. I also tried to switch twig into debug mode because then the translator should collect information, also to no avail.

So the question is how do I tell Symfony to use my `DataCollectorTranslator`?